# SQL query for data integrity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following structure

```
key1 varchar(255)
key2 varchar(255)
value decimal(6,2)
```

now i want to retrieve all tuples grouped on one of the keys where the value doesnt add up to a constant value say 1000.00.

Any idea how I can get this done using SQL?

SAmple data

```
key1 key2  value
1    2     480
1    3     520
2    3     200
2    4     300
2    5     400
```

In this case my query should return the last 3 rows.

Comment: Could you please add some sample data for the table and what the expected output should be.

Comment: None of your sample data summs values up to 1000, so actually it should return 5 rows and not just the last three... Is it possible that you only want rows that add up to `X mod 10 == 0`?

Comment: srry my bad... forgot to add 0s at the end.. :/

Comment: Huh I get it now... Should the question be: Group data by ONE KEY ONLY and if values add up to 1000 and return all valid rows ungrouped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;WITH t
     AS (SELECT *,
                SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY key1) AS s
         FROM   yourtable)
SELECT key1,
       key2,
       value
FROM   t
WHERE  s <> 1000
```

Comment: i modified the question slightly and  added sample data

Comment: @user917670 - you should hopefully still be able to use this answer, can see what you would need to change to just work with, say, `key1` and ignore `key2`.

Comment: yup I got it..this is what i was trying.

Comment: @Damien - Corrected. The original question mentioned `key1 key2 tuples`

Comment: select key1,key2 from (SELECT key1,key2,
                    SUM(value) OVER (PARTITION BY key1) AS s
             FROM   yourtable)) t where s<>1000